# How to web scrape Twitter with VBA using Chrome browser?

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape Twitter with VBA. The code worked fine for other website with the Internet Explorer, but as the Internet Explorer does not open Twitter website, I am trying to replace it with the Chrome browser. I found how to open a URL in Chrome but do not know what should I put to retrieve the data from the HTML document. Below, I kept the code that worked with Internet Explorer and added the codes opening Chrome browser. My main question is what I should put instead of "?????????" in the following code:

```
Sub GetData()
    
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim itemEle As Object
    Dim desc As String, a As String, title As String, titleDate As String
    
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
 
    Dim chromePath As String
    
    chromePath = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
    
    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    y = 2
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow
    
  
    sURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
    'Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    'objIE.Visible = True
 
    Shell (chromePath & Sheets("profileLinks").Cells(i, 1))
 
    'objIE.navigate sURL
    'Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    
    On Error GoTo err_clear
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    
    
    For Each itemEle In ?????????.document.getElementsByClassName("css-901oao css-bfa6kz r-111h2gw r-18u37iz r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0")
        Text = itemEle.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    
        Sheets("Outcome").Range("A" & y).Value = Text

        y = y + 1
    Next
    
    'objIE.Quit
    Next i
    
err_clear:
        If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
        End If
    
End Sub
```

Please feel free to suggest any other solution. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need additional object variables that can hold references to objects from the html object library. For example, after referencing to the Microsoft HTML Object library, you can add on sth like this:

```
Dim HTMLDocument As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim itemEle As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim itemCollection AS MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set HTMLDocument = objIE.Document
Set itemCollection = HTMLDocument.getElementsByClassName("...")

For Each itemEle in itemCollection
'extra code here
Next itemEle
```

I hope this answers your question!