# Vba Scraping Twitter details

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, twitter, screen-scraping

I have a list of Twitter urls in Column A, for which I am trying to pull some information off, however I am having a lot of trouble. I want to pull off everything in yellow

[image: Image of info]

I am not sure if it is due to having the wrong classes or due to the Twitter Urls NOT opening in excel. If I double click a url in excel and try to open it I get this error message.

[image: Url Error message]

The link works fine when I copy and paste them into the browser. I have read some information on the web that states that a HKEY on the PC may need changing [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-locate-server-when-click-hyperlink). The problem I have the person I am building this for is not pc literate and will struggle, to do any fix.

I have always used the below code for scraping and it has never failed me. When it does pull data off Twitter, I get an error message, see image below columns D + E. I am assuming this is making some contact to Twitter but can not access the page to extract the data. I am NOT using IE as it no longer works with twitter, I am using a MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.

[image: Twitter Error message]

This is what i am using to extract the data, it is the same for all the columns, just the class changes and if it is a Span or a child.

```
''''Element 3 Column D
        If doc.getElementsByClassName("css-1dbjc4n")(0) Is Nothing Then
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 4).Value = "-"
        Else
            wsSheet.Cells(StartRow + myCounter, 4).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("css-1dbjc4n")(0).getElementsByTagName("Span")(0).innerText
        End If
```

```
Public Function NewHTMLDocument(strURL As String) As Object

    Dim objHTTP As Object, objHTML As Object, strTemp As String
    
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHTTP.setOption(2) = 13056
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.send

    If objHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        strTemp = objHTTP.responseText
        Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        objHTML.body.innerHTML = strTemp
        Set NewHTMLDocument = objHTML
    Else
        'There has been an error
    End If
End Function
```

**QUESTION**

Is the problem due to the urls not opening in excel, or is it because the data is dynamic and it can not be extracted?

[Twitter Link 1](https://twitter.com/MotorHeadMag/)
[Twitter Link 2](https://twitter.com/dealerbuymycar/)

As always thanks for having a look and my apologies in advance for NOT adding HTML snippet as it would not let me post, I could not find the error so removed the html, it was stating that a URL had been shortened, but could not find it so removed the whole html snippet in order to post.

**UPDATE**

I thought this link was in my post, but I must have removed it when I removed the HTML Snippet. I found this on Stackoverflow but could not get it to work form me, nothing would extract [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62513312/how-to-web-scrape-twitter-with-vba-using-chrome-browser)

Comment: Using one of the Twitter APIs should be more reliable than trying to extract the data from the webpage of a Twitter user's profile. [This API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-by-username-username) could be a good place to begin

Comment: Double click does nothing for me. Single click opens the webpage. Your xmlhttp will not work as Twitter pages are javascript rendered. Look into the API method proposed.

Comment: QHarr, It does not work on my desktop as I have firefox, but on my laptop I have chrome and it worked fine, with a click. the issue is with the desktop browser or excel. i never thought of testing on my laptop. As for the xmlhttp, I came to the same conclusion as I have been doing some reading. I think i will have to give this a miss then as the person I am building for would run into all kinds of trouble with api if it expired.

Comment: The twitter API is far more reliable than writing a scraping script IMO. I don't see Twitter vanishing anytime soon (some countries aside maybe)....